# How to Change Cursor Theme, Speed and Size on Login Screen

Tags: 19.04, login-screen, cursor, cursor-theme

The question is that:

I've changed the cursor theme with **Tweaks** putting the cursor theme folder inside the:

> /usr/share/icons

I also changed the **speed** (with **dconf Editor**) in:

> /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/speed

and the **size** (with **dconf Editor**) in:

> /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-size

But... The login screen keeps showing me a default cursor **theme**, **size** and **speed**.

Answer (score 0):

While editing the file:

> /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults

You may change the cursor **theme**, **size** and **speed** as follows:

```
# Theming options
# ===============
[org/gnome/desktop/interface]
cursor-theme='Bibata_Ice'
cursor-size=35
[org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse]
speed=-0.8
```

Here, I'd used the **Bibata_Ice** theme, with size **35** and speed **-0.8**.

**Good lucky!**